# The name 'GimmePrimes' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-express

I am getting a error in C# while trying to access a static method inside another class.

This is the class trying to access it:

```
class Problem7
{
    public void Solve()
    {
        GimmePrimes(new long[]{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13});
    }
}
```

And this is the static class where GimmePrimes is located:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    //....Other static methods that work//
    public static IEnumerable<long> GimmePrimes(this long[] firstPrimes)
        {
            return firstPrimes.Unfold(priorPrimes => priorPrimes.Last().OddNumbersGreaterThan().SkipWhile(candidate => priorPrimes.TakeWhile(prime => prime * prime <= candidate).Any(prime => candidate.IsDivisibleBy(prime))).First());
        }
}
```

Both classes are in the same namespace.

Comment: You need longarrayname.GimmePrimes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Extensions` needs to be a static class.

```
public static class Extensions
```

Also, as it is an extension method, you're calling it wrong:

```
long[] array = new long[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 };
IEnumerable<long> primes = array.GimmePrimes();
```

On a related side-note, when I have extension method classes, I create a separate one for each type I am extending so that I don't end up with a huge monolithic class.

```
public static class IntExtensionMethods
public static class StringExtensionMethods
public static class IEnumerableExtensionMethods
```

etc.

Comment: It is a static class, sorry I didn't copy that over properly. Edited it to reflect the truth.

Comment: I noticed that you are also required to enter the `this.` prefix in the extended object when calling the extension method.